# How can I resolve a "[Errno 13] file not accessible" error?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, blobstore

My web application uses Django (django-nonrel) on Google App Engine. I am trying to open a Blobstore file.

My code successfully creates the Blobstore file and a Photo object to refer to the Blobstore's file name (along with some other metadata).

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files
import mimetypes

...

  file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=mimetypes.guess_type(request.FILES['photo'].name)[0])

  with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(photo_data)

  files.finalize(file_name)

  photo = Photo()
  photo.file_name = file_name
  ...
  photo.save()
```

However, trying to open the file produces the following error:

```
opened_file = open(photo.file_name)
```

> IOError at /post_photo_to_facebook/
>
> [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/blobstore/writable:NDNFUjNIVDdVQTM4Rk9aSE1aQkJMUzJUMzVDRVNRVEhJSjU3RUhWOE9ZMkk3QlNWR0FDR0JDOFUxSlA0Wlk3MA=='

Any help is appreciated - thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blobstore files are stored in, well, the blobstore. `open` is a function that opens files on the local filesystem (modulo special cases like *writing* blobs). As per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore), if you want to open the blobstore file after it's finalized, you need to call `files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)` on the filename to get the blob key object you should use to refer to the blob (and open it using `BlobReader`).

Comment: Thanks Nick, the special case was throwing me off. What is the file_name property that files.blobstore.create() returns useful for?

Comment: @bfox For creating the blob, as in the snippet. Once it's finalized, it's in the blobstore, and so should be accessed using its blob ID.